# What does "pattern" refer to in this context?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> The Catholic Church played a crucial role in the consolidation of
> secular power all over Europe. It was in the interests of the Church
> for the Crown to be able to protect its properties and servants
> against attack or abuse of authority by local chieftains and regional
> notables. **The pattern** was the same in both Sweden and Finland, which,
> after internal power struggles, were united into one kingdom under a
> single monarch in the thirteenth century. The Church was a consistent
> supporter of Crown interests, and when by the end of the same century
> the Crown’s military forces were moving their outposts further and
> further eastwards towards Karelia, the Catholic priests were hot on
> their heels. In the summer of 1293 Torgils Knutsson, the Swedish
> constable of the realm, led a successful military expedition to the
> Karelian Isthmus. The local Orthodox population was converted and a
> castle built in Viborg (Viipuri, now Vyborg, Russia), which remained
> the most important eastern frontier fortress in the realm until the
> early eighteenth century. (bolds by me)
>
> A hitory of Finland by Henrik Meinander

What does the word "pattern" refer to in this context?

My first thought was that the pattern is the way Finland and Sweden is united. Like both of them have had internal struggles.

But now I am confused and am not sure if my varians is correct or not.

Comment: The pattern is: "The Catholic Church played a crucial role in the consolidation of secular power all over Europe". They did the same thing in Sweden and Finland.

Comment: @gotube Your comment should be the basis for a good answer. Why not convert it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As user gotube wrote in a comment, *The pattern is: "The Catholic Church played a crucial role in the consolidation of secular power all over Europe". They did the same thing in Sweden and Finland.* More precisely, the pattern is the Catholic church supporting the monarch or central authority against more local authority figures, such as chieftains or local lords. The quote says that this happened in both Sweden and Finland. The pattern  was further that this support was one factor leading to national unity, or so the quoted text says.